# scipy matrix conversion documentation is unclear

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Im converting a dok to a coo matrix in scipy and the documentation seems unclear to me.
My goal is to not destroy the original matrix!
The documentation states:

> Convert this matrix to Compressed Sparse Row format.
> With copy=False, the data/indices may be shared between this matrix and the resultant csr_matrix.

However it seems to output the matrix rather than convert the original one.
I thought "copy" might change the behaviour from converting to creating a copy but testing shows that can't be true. My programm has a long runtime so i don't want to destroy the matrix accidentially right before exporting it :)

```
mat = scipy.sparse.dok_matrix((10,10),dtype=np.int16)
type(mat)
```

<class 'scipy.sparse.dok.dok_matrix'>

```
coo = mat.tocoo(copy=True)
print(type(mat))
```

<class 'scipy.sparse.dok.dok_matrix'>

```
print(type(coo))
```

<class 'scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix'>

```
coo = mat.tocoo(copy=False)
print(type(mat))
```

<class 'scipy.sparse.dok.dok_matrix'>

```
print(type(coo))
```

<class 'scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix'>

Thanks!

Comment: The matrix object refers to arrays which contain nonzero matrix entries, locations of those entries, etc. I think copy determine whether these other arrays are copied, or if both matrices refer to the same underlying arrays where possible. Try changing mat.data in your experiments for one matrix, and see if it affects mat.data in the other matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to worry about this, your `dok.tocoo` will always be a copy.  Also, methods like this always return a new matrix; they don't operate in-place.  The sharing applies to the underlying data structures that store values and indices, any only if they are similar enough.

The underlying data structure for a `dok` is a `dict`, for `coo` 3 numpy arrays.  There's no way to make the conversion without copying data.

They are being sloppy with the documentation here, just copying it from the generic template.  The `copy` parameter is relevant when doing a "same kind conversion", e.g. `dok.todok()` or a `coo.tocoo()`.  But application across formats will nearly always be a copy - I use 'nearly' because I'm unsure about a few like `csr.tocsc`.

If you are writing a function that takes a sparse matrix of any format, and needs to ensure it is, say, `coo`, you might want to use

```
 M1 = M.tocoo(copy=True)
```

to ensure that any changes of `M1` won't appear in `M`, even if `M` was already `coo`.

---

Your quote was from a `tocsr`.  The actual code for the `dok` version is

```
self.tocoo(copy=copy).tocsr(copy=False)
```

the `dok` is first converted to common `coo` format, and from there to `csr` (or one of the others).

The code for `dok.tocoo` is:

```
def tocoo(self, copy=False):
    from .coo import coo_matrix
    if self.nnz == 0:
        return coo_matrix(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype)

    idx_dtype = get_index_dtype(maxval=max(self.shape))
    data = np.fromiter(self.values(), dtype=self.dtype, count=self.nnz)
    row = np.fromiter((i for i, _ in self.keys()), dtype=idx_dtype, count=self.nnz)
    col = np.fromiter((j for _, j in self.keys()), dtype=idx_dtype, count=self.nnz)
    A = coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=self.shape, dtype=self.dtype)
    A.has_canonical_format = True
    return A
```